# Why does extracting `span` return `None` using BeautfulSoup4?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape [this site](https://www.banimode.com/1505/%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B4-%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA?page=2) and extract products (title, price), but when I use tag `<span>` to extract titles, it doesn't work.

I think I am entering the wrong tag.

```py
rom bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= "https://www.banimode.com/1505/%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B4-%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA?page=2"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , "html.parser")
print(soup.span.string)
```

But it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are there.*

---

Content is rendered dynamically and loaded via XHR that could be inspected via dev tools of your browser.

##### Example

```
import requests

data = requests.get('https://mobapi.banimode.com/api/v1/products?page_size=24&page=1').json()['data']['data']

for i in data:
     print(i['product_name'], i['product_price'])
```